# How do I handle thumbnails of white-on-transparent pngs in Bridge?

Tags: cs6, png, transparency, windows, adobe-bridge

When handling multiple white-on-transparent png images, I am hindered by the fact that the thumbnails of these images are all-white. Both Adobe Bridge CS6 and Windows Explorer suffer the same problem, I can't discern between two of these pngs.

Is there a way to make these thumbnails useful? Is there some setting I missed that allows changing the thumbnail background colour for a png -- now a deafult white?

Comment: nope.. doesn't seem to be any method to change the default white background where transparency exists. Very short-sighted on the part of Adobe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Adobe forums are any indication, this isn't possible. [This thread from 2010](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/581969) concludes that it isn't possible, and [this search](http://forums.adobe.com/community/search.jspa?peopleEnabled=true&userID=&spotlight=false&containerType=14&container=3261&rankBy=date&q=transparent+thumbnail) shows a smattering of chatter about the subject, all older but with no solutions.

I checked out the preferences (as you undoubtedly did) and didn't see anything myself in Bridge CS5.

If this information is outdated and a solution is available, then please correct me!

Comment: funny that in your search, I see some users complain about the standard *black*. Weird, and as Scott says, short-sighted. We can only hope for improvement in a future update.

Answer (score 1):

I Use a free image browser called [Lyn](http://www.lynapp.com) for exactly this problem, you can change the preview background in the settings. Mac only though.