# When saving images in photoshop CS6 as png they get a white background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png

I've got an image, it's an RGB 8 bit.

[image]

But when i save it as png, i don't see the transparency, it's all white

[image]

Comment: ..."I don't see the transparency" --- congrats, that's what transparency means.

Comment: @Ryan i mean it's all white. It's not saved as white and transparent

Comment: It is. It's just that your image previewer gives transparent images a white background by default. Try and place the image in a website, for example, with a non-white background, and you'll see that it did save out correctly. Related: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16040/how-do-i-handle-thumbnails-of-white-on-transparent-pngs-in-bridge

Comment: depended on the image viewer. most of the OS image viewers cant render the transparency as Photoshop do. they render transparency as white. and white over white will result what we can see here.

Comment: @Vincent you are right. Should we close this as duplicate?

Comment: We can do so if you're okay with that :)